# c and LD_PRELOAD. open and open64 calls intercepted, but not stat64

Tags: c, preload, system-calls, stat, interception

I've done a little shared library that tries to intercept open, open64, stat and stat64 sys calls.
When I export LD_PRELOAD and run oracle's sqlplus, I can see the traces of the open and open64 calls, but no traces of the stat and stat64 calls.
The shared library is a single c file with all the definitions of the sys calls in it.
Why does it happen that some syscalls are intercepted and others don't?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the GNU `libc` implements `open()` and `open64()` as you'd expect (i.e. they're just dynamically linked symbols that you can hook into with `LD_PRELOAD`), but does something special with `stat()` and `stat64()`.

If you look at the symbols exported by `libc` (e.g. with `nm -D /libc/libc.so.6`), you'll see that it doesn't actually provide the symbols `stat` or `stat64`!

Calls to these functions are wrapped - either at compile time (if possible) by inline functions in `<sys/stat.h>`, or (failing that) statically linked definitions provided by `libc_nonshared.a`.

The actual dynamically linked functions which are called are `__xstat()` or `__xstat64()`; and these take an additional first argument, an integer, which is a version number indicating the layout of `struct stat` that is expected by the caller.  Try hooking these instead.

(The point of all this is to allow the dynamically linked `libc` to support binaries which use various incompatible layouts of `struct stat` and definitions of bits in `mode_t`; if you look in `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` you'll find a comment to this effect.  `fstat()`, `fstat64()`, `lstat()`, `lstat64()` and `mknod()` are also affected in the same way.)

Comment: Hi Matthew. Thanks for your help. But I just noticed that the problem of not intercepting calls happens only with functions that have "struct stat64" as a parameter. It works for fstat, but not for fstat64 or stat64. Could it be a problem in my function definition? Or shall I intercept __xstat64 and __fxstat64? Thanks again.

Comment: @klayme: You're welcome, and thanks for accepting the answer - does that mean you got it to work OK?  (I think intercepting `__xstat64` and `__fxstat64` is right.)

Comment: This worked nicely for me when combined with the source at http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/sw/inodes64.html . They don't patch the 64-bit versions but only declare the interface. I patched them as well to allow a 32-bit compiler that was properly calling `stat64()` to handle 64-bit inodes.